# How to read csv without changing original datatypes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading csv and I do not want the dataypes of columns as object, they should be int, float, str etc.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path+files, delimiter='\t', error_bad_lines=False)

data.dtypes:
  Time       object
  Code        int64
  Address     object
  dtype: object
```

Is there any way that we could read datatypes originally as they are from csv while reading:

Expected:

```
data.dtypes:
  Time        int
  Code        int64
  Address     str
```

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df:
    A     B    C
    abc   10   20
    def   30   50  
    cfg   90   60
    pqr   str  50
    xyz   75   56
```

I want to get rid of the row where column 'B' is not 'int'. As the dtype of B is set as 'object' I am unable to do so.

Comment: Well, what is the format of time? If it's in a standard format, then you can use the `parse_dates` argument, but the documentation hints that typically you need to deal with this after the import `For non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_csv`. Also, there is no `str` type. The column will need to be `object`.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. The **only** type of CSV data is... text. Because CSV files are just text. Anything else is just an interpretation by a parser. I think that's what @ALollz is getting at.

Answer (score 5):

You can supply the `dtype` kwarg to `read_csv()`. From the docs:

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

e.g.

```
data = pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'Time': np.int64})
```

**Edit**: As @ALollz points out, this will break if the data in the specified column(s) cannot be converted. It is typically used if you want to read in data using different numbers of bits (e.g. `np.int32` instead of `np.int64`).

You can use `df['Time'].astype(int)` on the DataFrame with `ojbect`s to diagnose which data are causing the conversion issue.

Comment: The issue though, is that if `.read_csv` isn't already parsing the column as a numeric, then there are almost certainly non-numeric values in the column. Specifying a numeric `dtype` will you from parsing the file all together.

Comment: Agreed - this will force the type and break if the conversion doesn't work.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly set datatype. Is there any way where it will implicitly infer to the dataype from csv ?

Comment: @tejasshah it already does. If the inference is incorrect you should look at the data that is not of the correct type. You can use `df['Time'].astype(int)` to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Alex, that's exactly what's happening in my case. See the edited question

Comment: @tejasshah See CJ59 answer for your update question.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert columns pretty easily for numeric types:

```
data['Time'] = data['Time'].astype(int)
```

The dtype for your string field is stuck as an object though, because it's a string object. It would be possible I believe to create a new dtype that's explicitly string, but I don't know of any advantages to doing that.

For your edited problem, what you want to do is define a converter (because your file does NOT have a defined data type for the column)

```
import numpy as np

def col_fixer(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

data = pd.read_csv(file_path+files, delimiter='\t', converters=dict(B=col_fixer))
```

You can then discard rows with NAs however you'd like.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly set datatype. Is there any way where it will implicitly infer to the dataype from csv ?

Comment: It does that already. Your problem is that you want to *undo* that.

Comment: Tried in my solution, there is no change, still facing the error

Comment: Will the solution convert all the columns to int?

Comment: It will convert whatever columns you tell it to convert. The specific example that you have provided works correctly with the specific answer that I have given you; I can remove the offending row with `data.dropna()`. If it's not working for you, it may help to provide a real example of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To bypass Pandas' bad type inference, use a csv reader to feed strings to the DataFrame constructor.

```
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as fin:
    csv_data = io.StringIO(fin.read())
df = pd.DataFrame([*csv.DictReader(csv_data)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ex.csv 
# -0.11566111265093704,0.7655813,0
# 0.8792716084627679,0.82952684,1
# 0.5744048344633055,0.8762405,2
# -0.6245665678004078,0.24478662,3
# -0.33955465349370706,-0.042879142,4

curfile = pd.read_csv("ex.csv", dtype={0: np.float64, 1: np.float32, 2: int}, header=None)

print(type(curfile.iloc[0,0]), type(curfile.iloc[0,1]), type(curfile.iloc[0,2]))

# <class 'numpy.float64'> <class 'numpy.float32'> <class 'numpy.int32'>
```